# joining no of reports in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Hi I want to generate the report which will contain following things:
Daily report by country/destination against counts.

Eg.

No of contributions
No videos
No of experiences
Based on count yesterday, total for week, total for year for each destination.

I have written following query to count total for week.

```
select a.name, count(e.id),count(uc.id),count(v.id) 
from accommodation a, user_contribution uc,experience_video ev, video v,
(select id "ID",user_contribution_id,accommodation_id,case 
 when modified_on is null then trunc(created_on) 
 else trunc(modified_on) end last_modified from experience)e 
 where
      e.last_modified between trunc(sysdate)-7 and trunc(sysdate) and
      e.accommodation_id = a.id and
      e.user_contribution_id = uc.id and
      e.id = ev.experience_id and
      v.id = ev.video_id
group by a.name

union 

select l.name, count(ex.id),count(uc.id),count(v.id),count(r.id) 
from location l, user_contribution uc,experience_video ev, video v,
(select id "ID",user_contribution_id,location_id,case 
when modified_on is null then trunc(created_on) 
else trunc(modified_on) end last_modified from experience)ex 
where
    ex.last_modified between trunc(sysdate)-7  and 
    trunc(sysdate) and
    l.id = ex.location_id and
    ex.user_contribution_id = uc.id and
    ex.id = ev.experience_id and
    v.id = ev.video_id
group by l.name;
```

I can similarly write the query to extract weekly and yearly count.

basically I want all counts in one row for each destination.

Is there any better way of writing this query?

Would appreciate your help.

Comment: My problem is I want the report in following format.

Destination Name| ExpYesterdaysCount| Exp.WeeklyCount| ExpYearlyCnt| Contributionyestcnt| contributionweeklycnt| contributionyearlycnt|  videoyestcnt|  vdowklycnt| vdoyrlycnt|

Comment: What is the relationship between your query and the report that you want?  I find it hard to follow the logic.  Does that query work?